# Marking sent messages as read in Gnus over IMAP

Tags: email, emacs, imap, gnus

When using Gnus, I want my sent messages to be marked as read in the remote IMAP folder. I'm using

```
;; mark Gcc (group Cc) messages as read
(setq gnus-gcc-mark-as-read t)
```

but it doesn't work. Does this only work for offlineimap? Is there a way to do it for the remote IMAP Sent folder?

Comment: Works for me.. Are you also setting `gnus-message-archive-group` to something like `"nnimap:Sent Items"` (or whatever your imap server uses)?